# Java ME SDK not recognized by Netbeans/Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, java-8, java-me

I'm currently trying to use the Java ME platform for a project. However, I've spent several days trying to integrate the Java ME SDK with an IDE. I've downloaded/installed:

1. Java JDK
2. Both Netbeans/Eclipse, their respective Java ME plugins.
3. Java ME SDK (versions 3.4, 8.0, and 8.3)
   (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/downloads/index.html)

I've tried setting up the environment on my Mac, my Windows machine, and on a Windows VM. All attempts to install the software work fine. However, when I want to create a new Java ME project I'm required to point the IDE to the installed Java ME SDK. When I do this, **I get an error saying the IDE can't detect any platforms (or similar errors depending on the IDE).**      I'm relatively new to Java and I'm hoping the issue is something simple that I'm overlooking. 
Here is a screen cap of the error. I can post the device-manager log, but I'm not sure how to interpret it myself.

[Auto detection failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14LGq.png)

Comment: Things like these sometimes complain if you've installed different bit-versions of them. E.g. if you installed a 32bit JDK but a 64bit NetBeans - then NetBeans will only accept a 64bit whatever-else. (Just an example, don't know if this is the case in this specific setup, but I've seen it happen in other cases, so it could be worth a look).

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall netbeans and Java, but this time first install java me then netbeans, or you may install their combo. Download it here https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

go to [NetBeans website](https://netbeans.org/downloads/) and download the bundle including the Java ME sdk

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, I've tried this. The bundle seemingly only includes the plugins for Netbeans, not the platform itself. Netbeans still requires me to add Java ME platform (which it's having trouble detecting).

Comment: **For the Java ME SDK 8 EA you must use a special NB developer build, as described in the ME SDK 8 EA Getting Started Guide and the download page** [https://community.oracle.com/thread/3515212]

Comment: @stackmalux, your link is dead, btw

Comment: [https://community.oracle.com/thread/3515212 ] , the link is not dead, i fixed it by adding a space before the closing bracket, and thnx for the note @CodeToLife

Comment: Ok. Uninstalled all new  jdks except 1.7 and installed j2me 3.0sdk (with its framework inside). This runs great and  is enough for now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Donwload and install Java SDK 8u111 on [Java Archive Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase8-2177648.html)
2. Download Java ME SDK 3.4 or 8 on [Java ME SDK Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/downloads/index.html)
3. Install Java ME SDK like following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZN9KU.jpg)
4. After installation complete open Netbeans go to Tools > Platform manger > Add platform > Java ME CLDC Platform Emulator > next; after that choose the directory you have installed Java ME, click on next and follow the rest